# What is a single adverb for how something is supposed to be + verb

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Take the following sentence.

The object is usually stacked.

This perhaps implies that it is supposed to be stacked, but really only says that it is stacked most of the time.

Say the object is supposed to be thrown. How could I say, "The object is 'meantly' thrown."?

I'm looking for a single word that perfectly replaces supposed to be, such as "The document is supposed to be where the text appears." or "The document is supposed to be read."

Does it exist? If so, would there be an adjective form like usual is for usually?

Comment: I accidentally deleted a users comment. They were right that I was confusing syntax here, but my question about the adverb here still stands. Sorry please post your comment back I accidentally clicked edit instead of add a comment...

Comment: You're mixing up things here. *usually* is a modifier(adv.) in your sample sentence. *supposed* is a verb (that sentence being a _passivized version_ of _[They] suppose [others] to read the document_. The two sentences employ different syntaxes. It's vital that you understand how the constituents are pieced together in the the two sentences. In short, you can't find any such single word. If you try _supposedly_ and write _The document is supposedly read_, that would be a different sentence meaning something entirely different.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me.  An adverb modifies the verb; usually based on the _subject_. He ran the race quickly (HE was the one that did it quickly, not the race) She held the egg gently. (SHE did it gently, not the egg) I've tried and failed to think of an idiom or adverb where it is based on the _object_.   E.g. She ran the marathon NASCARly.  He groomed the dog horsely.

Comment: @Kevin. Right. I think the question is not answerable. I am going to make an answer and leave it at that. Someone else can if they offer a better explanation as to why this was a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

You could say, “This object is *conventionally* stacked,” and I think the most common interpretation would be “by convention, people stack this object”. (However, watch out for the alternative interpretation, “this object has been stacked in a manner that I judge to be conventional”.)

“Traditionally” can be used in somewhat the same way, although it is narrower in its connotations.

Comment: I am asking for a word that is quite similar to this. I would like to express the verb not by convention but by how it was originally intended. Like I said, saying the object is conventionally stacked would create a conflict in the scenario that the object is usually stacked but is supposed to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I've concluded that this question can't really be answered as the logic of it is flawed. The problem is that "X is supposed to be Y" is

[subject] + [auxillary to be] + [verb + to be] + [object].

where as "X is usually Y" is actually

[subject ] + [[adv...] to be] + [object].

Supposed is a verb, not an adjective. The error becomes clear when I change the sentence to active.

The document is supposed (by them) to be read -> (They) suppose others to read the document

The document is usually read( by someone) -> Someone usually read the document

I mistakenly thought that supposed could function as an adverb like "The document is supposedly read" but that actually unfolds to "(They) suppose that others read the document", not "(They) suppose others to read the document."